# Is it possible to get the "symbolic" matrix operator associated with a parameterized quantum circuit using Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, simulation, matrix-representation

Qiskit provides the [`qiskit.quantum_info.Operator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Operator.html) class to get the unitary matrix operator from the corresponding quantum circuit, as in the following example:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)

op = Operator(qc)
array_to_latex(op)
```

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt2} & 0 & 0\\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt2}
\end{bmatrix}

However, `Operator(QuantumCircuit)` raises an error in the case of a parametric quantum circuit:

```
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
theta = Parameter(name='$\\theta$')
qc.ry(theta, 0)

op = Operator(qc)  # ERROR!
```

This brings me to the question: is there a way in Qiskit to get the matrix operator symbolic representation from a given arbitrary PQC? For instance, in this case I would like to get a [`sympy.matrices.dense.Matrix`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/dense.html) object (with just one parameter $\theta$) like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & 0 & 0\\ 
\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\ 
0 & 0 & \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{bmatrix}

**EDIT**: this is now possible by using the new [`qiskit-symb`](https://github.com/SimoneGasperini/qiskit-symb) package

Comment: I don't think Qiskit uses sympy at all.

Comment: I think it does... At least sympy is included in the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/requirements.txt) file of the qiskit-terra repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this is currently possible. Here is a relevant open issue on the Qiskit repository. https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4751

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could convert your qiskit `QuantumCircuit` to a pytket `Circuit` using `qiskit_to_tk` and then use `circuit_to_symbolic_unitary`.

This does however involve installing the `pytket-qiskit` package so I'm not sure this really gives you what you're looking for tbh.

**EDIT:** pytket and qiskit use different qubit ordering conventions (see comments). Use `QuantumCircuit.reverse_bits()` before conversion to swap the ordering of the qubits. This reordering is necessary for the unitary to match the one in the question.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter

# define qiskit circuit as before
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
theta = Parameter(name='\\theta')
qc.ry(theta, 0)
```

Now convert circuit and display unitary

```
from pytket.extensions.qiskit import qiskit_to_tk
from pytket.utils.symbolic import circuit_to_symbolic_unitary

# optional to change qubit ordering -- qc = qc.reverse_bits() 
tkc = qiskit_to_tk(qc)
circuit_to_symbolic_unitary(tkc)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a way to do it in Qiskit but this is not possible at the moment so thank you anyway for the help. However, taking a look at your example, it seems that Qiskit and pytket are using a different qubits ordering convention and so the symbolic unitary matrix I would expect from Qiskit ($I \otimes R_y(\theta)$) is different from the one returned by pytket ($R_y(\theta) \otimes I$).

Comment: Yes, good point. Qiskit and pytket have opposite qubit ordering conventions. I should have mentioned that.

I'm a contributor to tket/pytket and I actually think it'd be nice to add an optional argument to reverse order the qubits when converting from qiskit. Would avoid some confusion I think. It already exists for the `tk_to_qiskit` function and should be fairly easy to add for the other direction. Thanks

Comment: In fact you can use the `QuantumCircuit.reverse_bits()` method before conversion to get the ordering correct.

Comment: Of course, thank you again. Just make sure that ```qc == tk_to_qiskit(qiskit_to_tk(qc))```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an operator to a state, and see the symbolic result.  Unfortunately, I can't find any way of getting this to work for an operator.

```
from sympy.physics.quantum.gate import CNOT, H
from sympy.physics.quantum.qapply import qapply
from sympy.physics.quantum.qubit import Qubit


qapply(CNOT(0, 1) * H(0) * Qubit('000'))
```

which will return
$$\frac{\sqrt2|000\rangle}{2} + \frac{\sqrt2|011\rangle}{2}  $$

It doesn't seem to have rotation operators, though you can write your own.  I'd love to find out how to just get the operator matrix.