# Given the following matrix representing a quantum gate, how do I implement it in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I have the following matrix and I need to build the corresponding quantum gate operator using Qiskit native gates (I guess phase and $CNOT$ is the universal set but I'm not sure):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+i\sinh\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)&0\\
0&\cosh\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)-i\sinh\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

How should I proceed in order to find a suitable sequence of gates implementing this operator?

Comment: Hi Alberto, just to clarify... do you mean - How do I find a quantum circuit to implement this unitary (i.e a sequence of gates)? The title of your question seems to ask for a way to express the  unitary as a tensor product of other matrices which I'm not sure makes sense for a single qubit unitary.

Comment: My bad, it's what you meant for this 2x2 case.

Comment: Do you mean to write sin and cos instead of sinh and cosh? The matrix you wrote is not unitary...

Comment: If it is sin and cos as opposed to cosh and sinh then this unitary is just an Rz gate . That's if you apply the complex exponential formula and assuming the minus signs match up

https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RZGate.html

Comment: This matrix is unitary only if $\theta=0$.

Comment: You should be more clear of what you mean by phase gate. Anyway, phase gate T and a CNOT do not form a universal set, you would need a Hadamard gate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your operator (let me call it $U$) is represented by a $2 \times 2$ matrix, so it simply acts as a rotation on a single qubit (no $CNOT$ or any other multiple-qubit gates are needed).

That said, $U = U(\theta)$, meaning that your operator is parameterized by an angle $\theta$ and, of course, the actual unitary matrix depends on the value assigned to $\theta$. Unfortunately, the latest Qiskit version (`qiskit-terra==0.22.4`) does not yet support the transformation of the parameterized unitary operator $U(\theta)$ into the corresponding parameterized quantum circuit (and, by the way, neither the other way around: take a look [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29384/is-it-possible-to-get-the-symbolic-matrix-operator-associated-with-a-parameter)). So, as far as I know, there is no way to get directly the general decomposition of $U(\theta)$ using Qiskit.

However, a workaround to the problem could be to implement a Python function `U(theta)` returning your operator as a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np

def U(theta):
    return np.array([[np.cosh(theta / 2) + 1j*np.sinh(theta / 2), 0],
                     [0, np.cosh(theta / 2) - 1j*np.sinh(theta / 2)]])
```

Then, you call this function (passing a specific value of `theta`) and you create the corresponding quantum circuit by the [`QuantumCircuit.unitary`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.unitary.html) method as follows:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
matrix = U(theta=<theta_value>)
qc.unitary(matrix, 0)
```

Comment: This code gives an error stating that the matrix is not unitary... because the matrix is not unitary... (Not your fault, I upvoted)